# How to change the dominant grub

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, xubuntu

I have two Linux installations on one disk: a [Parrot OS](https://www.parrotsec.org/) and an Xubuntu installation. When booted up, grub starts running from the Parrot partition and lets me boot into Windows and Xubuntu without problems. I'd like to remove Parrot and only have Xubuntu so I can have more free space. I've confirmed with *grub-install --version* that my Xubuntu install has grub installed. What changes do I have to make in order to boot grub from Xubuntu and not Parrot so I can remove Parrot?

Comment: `grub-install --version` doesn't tell you if grub is installed.  It only tells you the version of the `grub-install` app.   If you run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` and replace the X with your boot drive letter, it should then install the grub from Xubuntu over the Parrot OS grub.  Make sure to run `sudo update-grub` and make sure that Xubuntu is the top of the list then reboot the system.

Comment: I tried your approach but I only got an error about my GPT partition label containing no BIOS Boot partition. I refered to this (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174206/warning-file-system-ext2-doesnt-support-embedding-but-my-system-isnt-emb#329954) post about a similar problem and did notice that I had no /boot/grub/core.img file, could this be causing the issue?

Comment: I guess it could be.  I also have heard that you can turn on the BIOS boot partition by using `sudo parted /dev/sdX` then running `set 1 bios_grub on` so the flag is set for the first partition on the drive to now allow for grub installation.  Usually the boot partition is the one with the root `/` of your Ubuntu installation.  After the flag is set then you should be able to then run the `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`.

Comment: If you do not have bios_grub partition, then you have gpt, but Ubuntu installed in BIOS boot mode.  If drive is gpt, then Windows has to be UEFI, not BIOS. You need to convert Ubuntu to UEFI boot? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair